# TestFlight automatically creates new builds

Tags: ios, testflight

Since I began to use TestFlight, I constantly run into a weird issue : when an user (which I invited) downloads and uses my freshly uploaded build, TestFlight randomly creates new updates of my build, and an anonymous uses it and crash it without installing it or  even passing by checkpoints.

Here is my list of builds :

[image: List of builds]

The build #2 is the one I uploaded, and the #7 and #8 are created automatically *(I already deleted #3 to #6 to see if it would create new updates again)*

Here's what I get when I check #8 informations :
[image: Updated build]

And I can see that an Anonymous user successfully crashed my app on a x86_64 architecture, I believe this is a desktop iOS simulator :

[image: Weird user]

I can't find what I'm doing wrong, I think I followed the workflow without mistake, as I retried it 2 times.

I've checked online and I didn't find a similar case so far...

Do you have any clue of what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the software engineers at TestFlight I can provide some insight into this.

This was the result of new feature code in TestFlight recently added to display (and automatically add) builds from production (non-beta). If you leave the TestFlight SDK code in the application when you submit it to Apple's store, then TestFlight will receive events from those production builds - it will automatically create those production builds so that crashes from them can be monitored (independent of beta build crashes).

In order to better communicate these changes to TestFlight users, these production builds will be removed in the meantime and rolled out at a future date.

Comment: Alright! And as I didn't submit my app to the store yet, what could these x86_64 be? I let the `takeOff` code in the AppDelegate, and there is another developer who's using my code. Could that be the reason? I though that TestFlight would work only on real device...